# "И не только" в двух запятых (ежели посерёдке)? Что может означать "потеря смыслов" в таком-то веке?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

> И конечно же, после смерти Август был обожествлён. И многие из великих
>   италийских, **и не только,** семей **до самого конца XIX столетия, то
>   есть до начала потери человечеством смыслов**, *украшали* свои *жилища
>   образами* римской *мифологии* и портретами тех императоров, что
>   славились своим уважением к традиции и к «вере древних».

Ну и украсить жилище образом мифологии...

Comment: "начало потери человечеством смыслов" - трудновоспринимаемый набор существительных. Где-то у Розенталя есть, по-моему, подобные примеры плохих текстов.

Comment: Возможно, корректнее будет: "украшали свои жилища образами (в смысле изображениями) **из** римской мифологии"?

Comment: Уже предложено автору, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) **И не только (италийских)** можно обособить в качестве уточнения.

2) **Насчет человечества, потерявшего смыслы,** сложнее, это по контексту надо судить. Можно предположить, что это из такой темы:  "**сужение поля жизненных смыслов** вызывает переживание пассивности собственного бытия, а нередко и агрессивное отношение к окружающему миру".

3) ...украшали свои жилища образами (**символами**) римской мифологии.

Например: Сосна в японской литературе служит **образом** долголетия (художественным **символом** долголетия).

Answer (score 2):

1. Оговорка "и не только" разрывает существительное с назначенным ему прилагательным, поэтому для более естественного прочтения лучше заключить её в скобки.
2. Если автор хочет донести до читателя идею "*начала потери человечеством смыслов*", то надо её не как уточнение излагать (через "то есть" - как само собой разумеющееся), а начать с неё, а потом уже уточнить, когда это было, и заняться раскрытием тезиса (общая ли для человечества идея подразумевалась или повсеместно в это время начались утраты региональных идей и т. д.).